# Matlab compiler on linux error: "Cannot save logfile. You might not have permissions"

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, permissions, package

I'm trying to build a standalone MATLAB (R2013b) application on linux, using the  Application Compiler App.  I fill out the form to configure the build and click the "Package" button and immediately get a "Cannot save logfile.  You might not have permissions" error dialog.  I had left the "Create log file" option unchecked, though I believe this relates to the install-time log.

I scoured the preferences in MATLAB but was unable to find where a logfile location was specified.

I tried using the "Package App" button rather than the "Application Compiler" route, but found no way to include the MATALB Compiler Runtime through that interface, which I need.

Can anyone clarify where the log file is trying to be written, and if there is a way to control that?  Or, do I need to have root priv to run the compiler on Linux?

Thanks!

Jed

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried to make a .prj file in the same folder as the executable of the same name. Try deleting the executable and compiling it again.